# Удалился проект как восстановить?

Tags: c++, ide, восстановление

Ребята,очень срочно!!!Писал месяц проект,и щас накосячил,писал функцию очистки prefetch и эта уродка из за того что я походу в путях накосячил удалила все исходники.Я очень расстроен,я не знаю что делать,неужели ничего не сделать?
IDE: Visual studio 2019

Comment: это так смешно, что я поставил плюс)))

Comment: на будущее используйте системы контроля версий или бекапи.

Comment: Да я понимаю что надо было,но что щас делать,неужелиничего не сделать?

Comment: в общем, есть крайне большой шанс восстановить всё, что было. Качаете r-studio (нужна полная версия, т.к. у бесплатной там много ограничений). На тот диск, откуда удалилась инфа, до восстановления ничего записывать нельзя. Ну а дальше r-studio покажет, что она может восстановить

Comment: Еще студия кэширует некоторые исходники в темп-папках, но я точно не уверен где именно и как

Comment: рекувой прошеляся она ничего не нашла

Comment: Поэтому я люблю IDE от jetbrains, там хранится история изменений.

Comment: боюсь, что она бы также не помогла - у человека папку с проектом снесло.

Comment: Программы для восстановления удаленных файлов хорошо работают с большими бинарными файлами (типа видео), но не с большим количеством маленьких текстовых файлов, там трудно границы файлов определить. Даже если получится что-то найти, имена файлов будут потеряны, и структуру проекта нужно будет восстанавливать вручную.

Comment: Зато у вас теперь есть уникальная возможность написать с нуля более чистый код.